# Apply same argument to list of functions, and do an operation between each result

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a list of functions, each that take the same parameter, and return a number. I want to apply an argument to each function, and perform an operation (in this case subtract) on each successive result:

```
    const run = item => buyPrice(item) -
                        sellPrice(item) -
                        receivingCost(item);
```

Is there a clean, pointfree way to create this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not entirely point-free, but I think it takes care of certain complexities:

```
const run = lift((b, s, r) => b - s - r)(buyPrice, sellPrice, receivingCost)
```

While I'm sure we could create a point-free version of `(b, s, r) => b - s - r`, I really doubt that we could find one as expressive.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20buyPrice%20%3D%20%28item%29%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20sellPrice%20%3D%20%28item%29%20%3D%3E%202%2C%20receivingCost%20%3D%20%28item%29%20%3D%3E%203%0A%0Aconst%20run%20%3D%20lift%28%28b%2C%20s%2C%20r%29%20%3D%3E%20b%20-%20s%20-%20r%29%28buyPrice%2C%20sellPrice%2C%20receivingCost%29%0A%0Arun%28%7Bfoo%3A%20%27bar%27%7D%29)**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.map()` to call all the functions in the list, and then `Array.prototype.reduce()` to do all the subtractions:

```
function run (item) {
    const funcs = [buyPrice, sellPrice, receivingCost];
    return funcs.map(f => f(item)).reduce((x, y) => x - y);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't isolate the run function. In your solution, isn't `run` the result? I want it to be a function that can be called with `item`, and used to map over an array of items.

Comment: It would be trivial to wrap that in a function with an item and an array of functions as the arguments.

Comment: @mhodges I don't know what that means, so I ignored it.

Comment: @Ben Sorry, didn't notice that you were defining a function.

Comment: @Barmar [Point Free Javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=point+free+javascript&oq=point+free+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l4.2551j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: This is a great article, and series: http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/06/21/thinking-in-ramda-pointfree-style/

Comment: @Ben Can you take a look at my updated solution and let me know if that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on exactly what you're asking, but is this what you were looking for? The idea is to keep your functions in an array, and then use `R.reduce()` to subtract the result of each function call for a given item.

**EDIT** - Updated code to adhere more strictly to `Pointfree` standards by using function composition.

```js
const reduce = R.reduce;
const curry = R.curry;
const juxt = R.juxt;
const isNil = R.isNil;
var item = {
    buyPrice: 5,
    sellPrice: 8,
    receivingCost: 1
};

const getBuyPrice = R.prop("buyPrice");
const getSellPrice = R.prop("sellPrice");
const getReceivingCost = R.prop("receivingCost");

const fns = [getBuyPrice, getSellPrice, getReceivingCost];
const getItemPrices = juxt(fns);
const subtract = curry((a, b) => isNil(a) ? b : a - b);
const subtractArr = reduce(subtract);
const subtractArrFromFirstValue = subtractArr(null);
const run = R.compose(subtractArrFromFirstValue, getItemPrices);

console.log(run(item));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're trying to go point-free, why introduce a point in the final step?  Instead, `const run = R.compose(subtractArrFromFirstValue, getItemPrices)`.

Comment: Also note that `subtractArr` could written more simply as `reduce(subtract)`.

Comment: And if you're using the library anyway, `getProperty` is the same as [`R.prop`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop).

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you so much for the tips. I have not done much with Ramda or Pointfree coding, I just know about it from watching a course on Front End Masters, so some of the best practices/simplifications didn't come to me. What you've said makes total sense, and I have updated my answer accordingly. Thanks again.